# Using date -1day with wget

Tags: wget, date

I want to use wget with a cron job to pull a file every day, however I want it to pull the previous day's file from the remote server and the file is controlled by date variables in the URL as such:

```
http://example.com/export/file.csv?DateRange=20150429,20150429
```

I can pull the current date using this:

```
/usr/bin/wget --output-document=/file.csv "http://example.com/export/file.csv?DateRange=`date +%Y%m%d`,`date +%Y%m%d`"
```

This file is no good, though; I want to pull yesterday's date and not today's.

Is there a way I can subtract 1 day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU date, you can do:

```
date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d
```

For example:

```
$ date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d
20150430
$ date +%Y%m%d      
20150501
```

The command would be:

```
/usr/bin/wget --output-document=/file.csv "http://domain.com/export/file.csv?DateRange=`date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d`,`date +%Y%m%d`"
```

Check [the GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html) for more examples. You can also do:
`date --date='1 day ago'` or `date --date='-1 day'`.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly in shell when i run it manually, but if i add it to a cron, it doesnt run. I figured out that with the cron the `%` needs escaping with `\`

Comment: @MikeMeade yep. The crontab manual says `%` is for marking a newline, or something like that.