# Using date variable with wget --post-data

Tags: shell-script, cron, date, wget

For a project I want to use **wget** in a **cron** to download a data file. In the wget statement, a start- and enddate have to be defined in the following format:

```
wget --post-data="stns=235&vars=TEMP&start=YYYYMMDDHH&end=YYYYMMDDHH"
```

Since I want it to be done by a cron job, I would like the start- and enddate to be set automatically. More specific, I would like the startdate to be set to '1 hour ago' and the enddate to 'now'.

There has been a similar question in the post [Using date -1day with wget](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199828/using-date-1day-with-wget). Here the suggested solution was to put the variables between single quotes, but this did not work. E.g.:

```
"[...]start='`date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d%H'&end=`date +%Y%m%d%H`"
```

I simply got the error "Error 400: Bad request" when trying to execute the wget-statement in the terminal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a cron job, `%` is special and must be escaped. Also, backquote syntax is best avoided. I would suggest something like the following:

```
wget --post-data="start=$(date ... +\%Y\%m\%d\%H)&end=$(date ... +\%Y\%m\%d\%H)&..."
```